# Macbook Pro7,1 Ubuntu 14.04 external monitor

Tags: 14.04, hdmi, macbook-pro, external-monitor

I have a macbook pro7,1 and I have just installed ubuntu 14.04.

I try to connect it to an external Asus monitor, using a mini-display(thunderbolt) to HDMI wire.

I get an error message saying:

"Could not switch the monitor configurations 
could not set the configurations for critic 586"

Also nothing displays on the monitor and it says "HDMI:no signal"